# Under what visa category does my wife need to travel to the UK with me for two months, if I'm going there on a 1 year work permit visa?

Tags: standard-visitor-visas, family, working-visas

I am resident of India and my UK Work Permit is in stamping process ( 1 year). Since the work requiremnet is for 3-4 months as per company policy, company has not 
sposored dependant visa for my spouse and a kid as the duration is less than six month.
My tentative travel in second week of April. I woud like to take my wife and kid along with me for the similar or less period say 2 months.

What visa I should apply for my wife and a kid.. visitor visa/ family visit? should she mention in the visa form that she is going along with me and 
staying with me while I am on work.

While filling my business visa form, there was a field asking if anyone else is going with me.. I selected no.. as there were no plans.

so does the full iternary from return travel tickets to hotel/room booking needs to be submitted during visa processing.

My plan is to stay at my friends plce near london for initial couple of weeks by the time I get a rented place for myself near office.

Will my spouce and a kid will be allowed to stay for 2 months on a 6 months visitor visa? 
If she applies now mentioning my work permit detials in remarks and plan to travel along with me will it still need a confirmed iternaryas sid above?
Please guide about the category of visa and iernary docuemnts related to stay for 2 months with a husband who has UK work permit.

Comment: Moderators: I have answered, but cannot tell if this is a duplicate or not. Happy to see this question closed out if you find overlap to an existing question.

Answer (score 2):

Your spouse and dependants should apply for a [Standard Visitor Visa (SVV)](https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa/overview). Having a work permit adds nothing special by way of visa category for your spouse and dependants.   That page and [the guidance](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/visitor-visa-guide-to-supporting-documents) will answer all of your other questions, but let's recap them briefly here...

> What visa I should apply for my wife and a kid.. visitor visa/ family
>   visit?

The SVV (linked above) is the only possible mechanism for them to use.

> should she mention in the visa form that she is going along with me
>   and staying with me while I am on work.

Yes, there is a question like that on the form and we advocate honesty and full disclosure in visa applications, so she should put down all of your details when the form asks for them.  Note that each child must have their own application and fee, there are no 'family applications'.

> Will my spouce and a kid will be allowed to stay for 2 months on a 6
>   months visitor visa?

Yes, if visas are issued, they would expect your spouse and dependants to pursue their itinerary and enjoy their visit to the UK

> If she applies now mentioning my work permit detials in remarks and
>   plan to travel along with me will it still need a confirmed iternaryas
>   sid above?

No. They do not want to see confirmed reservations (or tickets). The premise and itinerary are sufficient. Read [the guidance](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/visitor-visa-guide-to-supporting-documents).

> Please guide about the category of visa and iernary docuemnts related
>   to stay for 2 months with a husband who has UK work permit.

Having a work permit enables **a premise** for a spouse and dependants and nothing more than that.  As far as visit visas go there are no other categories other than the Standard Visitor Visa.